# Regex .*? doesn't match everything

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that works for the following strings

1. `(?P<service>[a-z\-_]+)/(?<service2>[0-9]+)`
2. `(?P<stylesheet>[\/\s%\w\.\(\)\[\]\@_\-]+)/variations`

I first tried the following code for #1 and it worked as expected

Test 1: `'(?P<service>[a-z\-_]+)/(?<service2>[0-9]+)'.replace(/\(.*?<(.*?)>.*?\)/g, '{$1}')`

**Expected Output**: `'{service}/{service2}'`

**Result output**: Same

The same pattern doesn't work for #2 though.

Test 2: `'(?P<stylesheet>[\/\s%\w\.\(\)\[\]\@_\-]+)/variations'.replace(/\(.*?<(.*?)>.*?\)/g, '{$1}')`

**Expected Output**: `{stylesheet}/variation`

**Result Output**: `'{stylesheet}[]@_-]+)/variations'`

It leaves `[]@_-]+)` part.

How comes `.*?` doesn't match `[]@_-]+)` and how do I change my regex to work for both strings?

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you want? Please explain clearly.

Comment: @ArtBindu I want to have a regex that works for both #1 and #2.

The current regex works for #1, but not for #2

The expected output for #2 should be just `{stylesheet}/variations` without `[]@_-]+)`

Comment: Can you provide a clear input and expected output along with the code you are using? You have tagged Javascript, but I think `(?P<stylesheet>` is not the right syntax for a [named capture group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Backreferences) in Javascript.

Comment: @Thefourthbird // Sorry for the confusion. That isn't a regex actually. That's just string. 

Input: `(?P<service>[a-z\-_]+)/(?<service2>[0-9]+)`
Expected output: `'{service}/{service2}'`

It works fine, but the 2nd one doesn't

Comment: @Thefourthbird I've updated the post a bit (added expected and result out). Hope that helps.

Comment: The issue is happening `\(\)` this section at the second input string. regex `/\(.*?<(.*?)>.*?\)/g` considering `(?P<stylesheet>[\/\s%\w\.\(\)` as first part. You have to create a regex ignoring the consecutive two first brackets, () parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assert either a `/` to the right or the end of string `(?=\/|$)` using a positive lookahead:

```
\(.*?<([^<>]*)>.*?\)(?=\/|$)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dsVywb/1)

```js
const regex = /\(.*?<([^<>]*)>.*?\)(?=\/|$)/gm;

[
  `(?P<service>[a-z\\-_]+)/(?<service2>[0-9]+)`,
  `(?P<stylesheet>[\\/\\s%\\w\\.\\(\\)\\[\\]\\@_\\-]+)/variations`
].forEach(s => 
  console.log(s.replace(regex, `{$1}`))
)
```